# How to implement session time out in OpenERP

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I want to automatically logout from OpenERP session if session time is more than 30 min.

Comment: Please accept Yaseen's answer if it worked for you.  (Click on the check mark near his answer's score.)

Answer (score 6):

This can be done by editing the `session_gc` method in `.../addons/web/http.py`.  The following code illustrates your need -- remove or comment out the `if` condition (and un-indent the following lines accordingly):

```
def session_gc(session_store):
    #if random.random() < 0.001:
        # we keep session one week
        last_week = time.time() - x
        for fname in os.listdir(session_store.path):
            path = os.path.join(session_store.path, fname)
            try:
                if os.path.getmtime(path) < last_week:
                    os.unlink(path)
            except OSError:
                pass
```

The `x` is the number of seconds for timeout as per your need.

Comment: Thanks a lot.It is working perfectly.Before I missed to remove IF condition.once again thanks alot